# How to search index of an object having a certain property in list?

Tags: ios, swift, list

Assuming i have a list of objects and objects has a property named as key.
how can i search for index of the object which has a key of 1.

Comment: `func firstIndex(of:)` (Returns the first index where the specified value appears in the collection.). It took about 5" to locate in the swift documentation.

Answer (score 3):

```
let index = yourList.firstIndex {$0.key == "yourKey"}
```

should return the first index if exists.